# iOS: Telling Accessibility to read aloud specific part of a UIWebView?

Tags: uiwebview, accessibility

I want to add an HTML P tag to a UIWebview, and when I do so I'd like the Accessibility feature, if it is enabled, to automatically read aloud the new text that is in the P tag.

Is such a thing possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed possible, but not consistently implemented on iOS.

Use live region markup like:

```
aria-live="polite"
```

or

```
 role="status"
```

If the parent DOM element has live region markup attributes on it, then adding text content to a child will speak it as it is added.

Placing a `role="alert"` on the structure your adding will cause the screen reader to say *"alert"*, followed by the text contained in the structure your adding.

See the following for more on live regions:

- http://pauljadam.com/moderna11y/#wai-aria
- http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/

Comment: aria-live="polite"  only speak but not focus. and aria-selected="true" maybe a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this can be done. The only way I could think to do this would be with WAI-ARIA live regions. It does not appear that Voiceover supports live regions since the following WAI-Aria demo worked fine in firefox using Jaws as the screen reading software but did not work on iOS 4.3.5 using voiceover on an iphone 4.
http://test.cita.uiuc.edu/aria/live/live4.php